# Vue looping with modulus

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

How to do `looping` for `each two data` using modulus? In case I want to do a looping for `every two data` get a sequential class. Example :

I have 6 data :

- Data A
- Data B
- Data C
- Data D
- Data E
- Data F

So the final result I want to make is to give the class to each data with modulus `every two data`. I will have results :

- Data A | Class 1
- Data B | Class 1
- Data C | Class 2
- Data D | Class 2
- Data E | Class 3
- Data F | Class 3

The `class name` will always be `increased` using the `counter` if any new data is entered.

I have created the sample code below :

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            items: [{
                "id": "111",
                "nama": "George",
            }, {
                "id": "222",
                "nama": "Paul",
            }, {
                "id": "333",
                "nama": "Mira",
            }, {
                "id": "444",
                "nama": "Doms",
            }, {
                "id": "555",
                "nama": "Brian",
            }, {
                "id": "666",
                "nama": "Oscar",
            }]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        computedClass(index) {
            defValue = 1
            if (index % 2 === 0) {
                return "data_1"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.item {
  padding: 10px;
}
.data_1 {
  color: #FF0000;
}
.data_2 {
  color: #0000FF;
}
.data_3 {
  color: #00CC00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="item"
      :class="computedClass(index)"
       v-for="(item, index) in items">
       {{item.nama}}
       </div>
</div>
```

but I am confused to do `counter and modulus` so that every two data I get the name of the class is also being `incremented with counter`.

In my code above, I can only do modulus of `every second data`. Not `every two data`. And I am confused to do class naming with counter

Can you help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but your logic is wrong in the `computedClass` method.

Try this instead:

```
computedClass(index) {
  return "data_" + Math.ceil((index + 1) / 2);
}
```

---

Here's a working example:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{"id": "111","nama": "George",},{"id": "222","nama": "Paul",},{"id": "333","nama": "Mira",},{"id": "444","nama": "Doms",},{"id": "555","nama": "Brian",},{"id": "666","nama": "Oscar",}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    computedClass(index) {
      return "data_" + Math.ceil((index + 1) / 2);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  padding: 10px;
}
.data_1 {
  color: #FF0000;
}
.data_2 {
  color: #0000FF;
}
.data_3 {
  color: #00CC00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div 
    class="item"
    :class="computedClass(index)"
    v-for="(item, index) in items"
  >
    {{item.nama}}
  </div>
</div>
```